# inner query issue

Tags: sql, inner-query

I have a doubt regarding an inner query

Schema:

- `DEPARTMENT` (*deptnum*, descrip, instname, deptname, state, postcode)
- `ACADEMIC` (*acnum*, deptnum*, famname, givename, initials, title)
- `PAPER` (*panum*, title)
- `AUTHOR` (*panum*, acnum**)
- `FIELD` (*fieldnum*, id, title)
- `INTEREST` (*fieldnum*, acnum**, descrip)

I have the output in this format :

```
select 
    acnum, title, givename, famname
from  
    academic a 
where 
    a.acnum in (select count(*) as no_of_papers, acnum 
                from author auth 
                join paper p on auth.panum = p.panum
                group by acnum 
                having count(*) < 20)
union
select 
    acnum, title, givename, famname
from 
    academic a 
where 
    a.acnum not in (select count(*) as no_of_papers, acnum 
                    from author auth 
                    join paper p on auth.panum = p.panum
                    group by acnum);
```

However along with the fields in the select statement of the outer queries, I also want the `count(*)` as `no_of_papers` in the result set.

I have been breaking my head for quite some time now.

Comment: Why not `join` to the inner query rather than using it in a `where` clause?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**Join**](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/joins.php)

Try Like this

```
SELECT acnum,title,givename,famname,no_of_papers
FROM academic a JOIN
( 
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS no_of_papers,acnum 
    FROM author auth JOIN paper p ON auth.panum=p.panum
    GROUP BY acnum HAVING COUNT(*)<20

)x ON 1 = 1
WHERE a.acnum IN (x.acnum)

UNION 

SELECT acnum,title,givename,famname,no_of_papers
FROM academic a 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS no_of_papers,acnum 
    FROM author auth JOIN paper p ON auth.panum=p.panum
    GROUP BY acnum

 )y ON 1=1
WHERE a.acnum NOT IN (y.acnum)
```

Comment: Why this "obfuscated" join and not `join (...) x on a.acnum = x.acnum`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a union:

```
select 
  a.acnum,
  MIN(a.title),  -- only 1 value anyways if acnum is a primary key
  MIN(a.givename),
  MIN(a.famname),
  count(p.panum) as no_of_papers
from academic a
left join author auth on a.acnum = auth.acnum
left join paper p on auth.panum = p.panum
group by a.acnum
having 1 = 1 -- ??? no_of_papers < 20 ???
;
```

Comment: Group by should include all columns same as select column list right ?

Comment: @JaydipJ Questioner's group by was always on `acnum` which seems to be a unique key of the academics table.

Comment: @ebyrob It will error out if you don't include all non-aggregate columns. You need to `GROUP BY a.acnum, a.title, a.givename, a.famname`

Comment: @ebyrob-I have used union so as to include the result for acnum that have not written any paper
eg
acnum not in (those acnum that have written a paper)

Comment: @Eric that really depends on the type of SQL database and options specified.  (but I added `MIN()` around those values just in case)

Comment: @PandyaG a `LEFT JOIN` will also include those missing rows.